# Rotate UI Button

Tags: rotation, uibutton

I currently have a few lines of code that start a timer when a button is pressed.

```
- (IBAction)startTimer:(id)sender {
    [timer invalidate];
    timer= [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:60.0 target:(self) selector:(@selector(tick)) userInfo:(nil) repeats:(YES)];

}
```

How would I make the button rotate when I press it, and continue until the timer is stopped?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT2: Here is my second attempt at adding the code:

```
-(void)tick{
    timeTick++;
    NSString *timeString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%d", timeTick];
    labelTime.text = timeString;
    [_startButton setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(6.283185307)];



}
```

It says that startTimer: is undeclared. What should I type there to make this work?

Comment: Do you mean rotate in plane (like a clock) or rotate like flipping and then showing the backside?

Comment: @DerWOK I would like it to rotate in plane like a clock.

Comment: '[startTimer:' should be '[_yourButton '

Comment: @juniperi It still states that it is an undeclared identifier. Ideas?

Comment: Ok, so do you have reference outlet for your button in your viewController.h file? And update tick method in your post.

Comment: @juniperi I have an IBAction called startTimer: in my .h file. Does this work? I updated tick method.

Comment: yourButton must be the name of your button in .h file. Make sure you have reference outlet in .h file and put right name to your tick method.

Comment: You have to link your button from storyboard to your .h file. Press ctrl and drag with mouse from storyboard to .h file (use assistant view)

Comment: @juniperi When I tried using your method, it crashed my app and doesn't show an error in the console. What's up with that?

Answer (score 1):

To rotate UIButton:

```
[_myButton setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(angle)];
```

> ## angle
>
> The angle, in radians, by which this matrix rotates the coordinate system axes. In iOS, a positive value specifies counterclockwise rotation and a negative value specifies clockwise rotation. In OS X, a positive value specifies clockwise rotation and a negative value specifies counterclockwise rotation.

Angle in radians = angle in degrees * (M_PI / 180)

Comment: I attempted adding the code. Look at my edited question to see exact code. What went wrong?

Comment: @PanicDev put that rotation code to your `tick:` method. And don't use degrees, you have to use radians.

Comment: I have tried to apply your advice and got the result posted in the edit above. Thoughts?